# How to change value of an array in knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, knockout.js

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" data-bind="visible: application.candidateMostRecentAcademic" style="display:none;">
        <span>Education:</span>
             <!-- ko if: application.candidateMostRecentAcademic != null -->
               <!-- ko with: application.candidateMostRecentAcademic[0] -->
                 <span data-bind="text: $data.degreeTypeName"></span>
                 <span data-bind="text: $data.institutionName"></span>
                 <span data-bind="text: $data.dateToYear"></span>
               <!-- /ko -->
             <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I was going to make the the column visible only if application.candidateMostRecentAcademic (array) exists.

But I also wanted to add a condition for an array that has 0 length (which is not null).

So when I tried to do,

```
<div class="col-md-6" data-bind="visible: application.candidateMostRecentAcademic.length != 0" style="display:none;">
```

it gave me an error saying that it cannot access the "length" of a null object. So, what I am trying to do is, I want to set an array of length 0 to null so that it can just be invisible just like the null object.

How can I do this with knockout data-binding?

Comment: Can you share the viewmodel?

Comment: Can you initialize the array in your ViewModel as `application.candidateMostRecentAcademic = []` so that it'll never be null but by default, the length will be 0, which will not throw the error as you described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want your `if` statement to pass if the Array is not `null` and if it's `length` is not equal to `0`?

If this is the case, you could do this in your template:

```
<div class="col-md-6" data-bind="visible: application.candidateMostRecentAcademic && application.candidateMostRecentAcademic.length !== 0">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another member in viewmodel called isColumnVisible and use this member to show and hide column.

```
var viewModel={
    isColumnVisible=true;
    loadData:function(){
        // code to load data;
        // application= something
        if(application.candidateMostRecentAcademic ===null){
            this.isColumnVisible=false;
        }
    }
}
```